# Not able to click on span using selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I have following code in which I want to click on span,

```
<div class = "class1">
    <button class="class2 class3 class4 class5" role="button" type="Button">
        <span class="class6">Add</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

What should be the correct code to click on Add button?

I am using Firefox driver.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to click on the span element. A span element is not clickable. However, it looks like you can click it because it is inside a button.

All you need to do is locate the button element instead of the span and click on this.

Answer (score 0):

Use an Xpath as below:-

```
//div[@class='class1']//span[@class='class6']
```

Try code as below:-

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='class1']//span[@class='class6']")).Click();
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

As has commented, you don't need to click in span tag, but only in the buton. Some simple selector like this can help you:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.class1 > button.class2")).Click();
```

Answer (score -2):

You can add an action using the `onclick` handler (though I'd recommend putting it on the button):

```
<div class = "class1">
    <button onclick='alert("hello world")' class="class2 class3 class4 class5" role="button" type="Button">
        <span class="class6">Add</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

You can add whatever JavaScript you want in the `onclick` handler.

Comment: I don't have any control on html code. I can't change it. The scenario is I want to click on the add button on a pop-up to add a tab. This scenario I want to automate using selenium webdriver. Would you please elaborate your answer.

Comment: Can you run JavaScript in the context of the html?